# Comparision of numeric values with two variables in Terraform templatefile template

Tags: terraform, terraform-template-file

I'm trying to create a rendered file with Terraform's templatefile function.

Here is my code:

```
variable "prefix" {
  default = "k8s"
}

variable "masters_count" {
  default = 2
}

resource "google_compute_address" "k8s-static-ips" {
  name = "${var.prefix}-${count.index}"
  count = var.num_k8s_nodes
}

locals {
  ips = {
    for k in google_compute_address.k8s-static-ips : k.name => k.address
  }
}

resource "local_file" "AnsibleInventory" {

  content = templatefile("inventory.ini.tmpl",
  {
    private = local.ips
    prefix = var.prefix
    masters_count = var.masters_count
  }
  )
  filename = "inventory.ini"
}
```

```
[all]
%{ for index, ip in private ~}
${prefix}-${index} ansible_host=${ip} 
%{ endfor ~}

[kube-master]
%{ for index, ip in private ~}
%{ if index < masters_count ~}${prefix}-${index}%{ endif ~}
%{ endfor ~}

[calico-rr]

[k8s-cluster:children]
kube-master
kube-node
calico-rr
```

I have the problem that the `%{ if index < masters_count ~}` condition does not work, I am getting the Terraform error:

```
Call to function "templatefile" failed: inventory.ini.tmpl:11,7-12: Invalid
operand; Unsuitable value for left operand: a number is required., and 4 other
diagnostic(s).
```

Looks like it doesn't know the index variable in the if block.
How can I make the comparision of that line possible accessing the index variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it differently now.

```
[kube-master]
%{ for index, ip in private ~}
%{ if tonumber(element(split("-",index),1)) < masters_count ~}${index}
%{ endif ~}
%{ endfor ~}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `local.ips` will be a **map** of the form:

```
{
  "addressname1" = "ip1"
  "addressname2" = "ip2"
}
```

Therefore, in your template when you write `%{ for index, ip in private ~}`, `index` **will be string** (e.g. `addressname1` and `addressname2`), not a number. This means that you can't use `index` in the if expression.

It is not clear what do you want to achieve with `local.ips` and the `for` loop in the template. But if you use the following in `AnsibleInventory`, it will at least work:

```
private = values(local.ips)
```